# absctractmethods: how to make the code fail on class definition, not instance creation?

Tags: python, abstract-class, metaprogramming, abstract-methods

Something I don't like about `@absctractmethod` is that it only produces error when the instance is created. For example, this will not fail:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class AbstractClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def func(self):
        pass


class RealClass(AbstractClass):
    pass
```

it will only fail if I create an instance:

```
r = RealClass()
```

I want to reimplent this mechanism but so that it fails on class definition, not instantiation. For this, I created a metaclass:

```
class ABCEarlyFailMeta(type):

    direct_inheritors = {}

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):

        klass = super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict)

        class_path = clsdict['__module__'] + '.' + clsdict['__qualname__']

        if bases == ():
            # we get here when we create base abstract class.
            # The registry will later be filled with abstract methods
            cls.direct_inheritors[class_path] = {}

            for name, value in clsdict.items():
                # adding abstract methods on the proper base abstract class
                if getattr(value, '__isabstractmethod__', None) is True:
                    cls.direct_inheritors[class_path][name] = signature(value)

        else:
            # we get here when create inheritors.
            # Here, we need to extract list of abstractmethods
            base_class = bases[0].__module__ + '.' + bases[0].__qualname__
            abstract_method_names = cls.direct_inheritors[base_class]

            # here, we compare current list of methods
            # with list of abstractmethods and fail if some methods are missing
            cls_dictkeys = set(clsdict.keys())

            missing_methods = set(abstract_method_names) - cls_dictkeys
            if missing_methods:
                raise Exception(
                    f'{clsname} must implement methods: {missing_methods}'
                )

        return klass
```

this will fail when class is created, not instantiated:

```
class ABCEarlyFail(metaclass=ABCEarlyFailMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def func(self):
        pass


class Child(ABCEarlyFail):
    pass

>>> Exception: Child must implement methods: {'func'}
```

My question is, how do search for proper base class in `bases`? In this example, I look for `bases[0]`, but it will fail if the inheritor class has a mixin:

```
class Child(SomeMixin, ABCEarlyFail):
    pass
```

so, what is a nicer way?

Or maybe I am reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Why are you only considering `bases[0]` in the first place? Ordering among base classes is only relevant for constructing the MRO; there's nothing otherwise special about the first one versus the others.

Comment: FWIW, you *could* want to do `RealClass.func = foo` *after* the actual `class` definition…

Comment: @chepner yeah - I can search through all of `bases`, but it looks fragile and hacky anyway.

Comment: @deceze yeeeah - i have enough magic on my hands already :)

Comment: One feature of deferring the abstraction check until instantiation is to allow the child of an ABC to *also* be an ABC. Your approach disallows that, unless you add a way to explicitly mark a class as being abstract (thus disabling the requirement to override any inherited abstract methods concretely).